# How to transform data from WITH statement to collection?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
WITH doorbot_data AS
(SELECT id FROM doorbots WHERE)

SELECT dings.id, doorbots.id
FROM dings
INNER JOIN doorbots ON dings.doorbot_id = doorbots.id
WHERE doorbots.id = ...   <---
      and deleted_at is null
ORDER BY dings.created_at;
```

First I select `doorbot_data`, it's like a collection of `id's`.

Then I want to use it in `WHERE` like: `WHERE doorbots.id = doorbot_data.id`. But when I run it I got `missing FROM-clause entry for table "doorbot_data"`

Everything is working fine if I use some `id` like `123`:

```
SELECT dings.id, doorbots.id
FROM dings
INNER JOIN doorbots ON dings.doorbot_id = doorbots.id
WHERE doorbots.id = 123   <---
      and deleted_at is null
ORDER BY dings.created_at;
```

So I think I need to transform `doorbot_data` to array and use it like
`WHERE doorbots.id IN (_array_)`. Is it the correct idea? How to do this?

Comment: `Is it the correct idea? How to do this?` A *commalist* is a terrible idea. Just use `WHERE id IN(subquery)` or `WHERE EXISTS( correlated_subquery)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for simple join?:

```
WITH doorbot_data AS
(SELECT id FROM WHERE)
SELECT dings.id, doorbots.id
FROM dings
INNER JOIN doorbots ON dings.doorbot_id = doorbots.id
JOIN doorbot_data ON doorbots.id = doorbot_data .id
ORDER BY dings.created_at;
```

Comment: but if you use CTE - you have to select from it - otherwise how you put it to the query? to which part?.. and what is the problem with join?..

Comment: `doorbot_data` it's data from `doorbots` so I don't want to do unnecessary work (join)

Comment: self join not always is unnecessary job. next time to avoid such misunderstanding, don't collapse code to `(SELECT id FROM WHERE)`, but put a real one

Comment: Sorry about that, could you please update your answer regarding the comments?

Comment: please put the whole query. you ask to build a query and hide it

Comment: ... and add some table aliases (and **use** them) to show where the fields stem from.